# Looking for some ideas to visualize an interactive 2d matrix in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, matrix

I am trying to make a 2d matrix visualization which is interactive to the user. In other words the user is able to click on each cell and manipulate it and also "move around" the grid. The matrix will be on the order of 1000X1000 or larger but my viewing rectangle is intended to be only about 50X50 so I want the user to be able to move the viewing rectangle around the matrix. The logic concerning the matrix is all written in java so I was trying to use the Swing library as a start. For now I had some simple old minesweeper type of look in mind but since I am not very experienced with GUI stuff I was trying to get some ideas or suggestions on what tools to use or some general ideas on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it simple I recommend using Quartz2d for it, I image its the most similar way to the code you had in Java,
there s really good (non swift) tutorial here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/series/graphing-with-quartz-2d/
a very simple example in swift would be:

```
class Graphic: UIView {
var rows:Int = 10
var columns:Int = 20
var spacing:CGFloat = 10

var currentFocus:CGPoint = CGPointZero

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let width = rect.width / CGFloat(columns)
    let height = rect.height / CGFloat(rows)

    for var row = 0; row < rows; ++row {
        for var column = 0; column < columns; ++column {

            let rect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(column)*width, CGFloat(row)*height, width - spacing, height-spacing)

            if CGRectContainsPoint(rect, currentFocus) {
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255.0/255.0, 115.0/255.0, 155.0/255.0, 1)
            } else {
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 90.392157, 0.584314, 0.929412, 1)
            }


            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        }
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInView(self)

    currentFocus = location

    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

}